# Combobox selection highlight in LWUIT

Tags: combobox, lwuit

I have a combobox in LWUIT and when I use my arrows up and down I can't see which item is selected so How can I change the background color of combobox item selected in LWUIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer, I have used Cell Renderer to be able to change the Style of ComboBox Item and also I have used Look and Feel to be able to change the arrow Icon and replace it with my Icon

```
genderCB.setListCellRenderer(my defined cell renderer);
```

> Blockquote

```
 LookAndFeel lf = UIManager.getInstance().getLookAndFeel();
        try {
            ((DefaultLookAndFeel) lf).setComboBoxImage(Image.createImage(image));

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ComboBox`UIID ComboBoxFocus Selected style.